# How to declare a port Range in Tye?

Tags: .net, docker-compose, tye

In docker compose I can declare a port range as

```
ports:
  - "10250-10254:10250-10254"
```

Is there a way to do this using [Tye](https://github.com/dotnet/tye) other than listing them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the current [tye schema](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/tye/main/src/schema/tye-schema.json) it looks like you must define each port one by one.